# How to normalize this simple API response using "normalizr"?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have this response coming from an API ...

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_id": 1,
            "creator_id": 1,
            "instructor_id": 1,
            "difficulty_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "title": "hebae",
            "overview": "Course Overview",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-01-02 15:16:08",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-02 15:16:08"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category_id": 1,
            "creator_id": 1,
            "instructor_id": 2,
            "difficulty_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "title": "update course 1",
            "overview": "Course Overview",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-01-02 15:18:40",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-02 15:19:06"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "category_id": 1,
            "creator_id": 1,
            "instructor_id": 1,
            "difficulty_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "title": "hebaTest",
            "overview": "Course Overview",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-01-02 15:24:09",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-02 15:24:09"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category_id": 2,
            "creator_id": 1,
            "instructor_id": 1,
            "difficulty_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "title": "hebaTest",
            "overview": "Adile",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-01-02 15:25:03",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-02 15:25:03"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "category_id": 2,
            "creator_id": 1,
            "instructor_id": 1,
            "difficulty_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "title": "hebaTest",
            "overview": "Adile",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-01-02 15:33:06",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-02 15:33:06"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "category_id": 1,
            "creator_id": 1,
            "instructor_id": 1,
            "difficulty_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "title": "Course Title",
            "overview": "Course Overview",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-01-05 08:24:56",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-05 08:24:56"
        },
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://skillboardbackend-staging.zph2jwe3pc.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/course?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    "last_page_url": "http://skillboardbackend-staging.zph2jwe3pc.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/course?page=2",
    "next_page_url": "http://skillboardbackend-staging.zph2jwe3pc.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/course?page=2",
    "path": "http://skillboardbackend-staging.zph2jwe3pc.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/course",
    "per_page": 15,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 15,
    "total": 29
}
```

I'm trying to get the "data" array to be defined as "categories" object, and the rest data can stay the same, how to do that with normalizr?

I tried this ...

```
const { data } = await apiGetAllCategories();

const dataSchema = new schema.Entity("categories");
const coursesSchema = new schema.Entity("info", {
    data: [dataSchema]
});
const normalizedData = normalize(data, coursesSchema);
console.log(normalizedData);
```

But it always gives me the "info" as undefined, and the "result" as undefined ...

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Above API response doesn't seem to be so deeply nested it requires extra library to extract any data. Show us desired output data sample and I'm pretty sure there's a simple vanilla js solution to suggest.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  I simply need the same structure as the response, except for the data to be an object instead of an array, and the keys of this object is the id, just like what I got from "normalizr" in the "categories" in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested in how to normalize this response with "normalizr", I figured out where I went wrong, and that `normalizr` usually looks for and an "id" key at the top level, and if it can't find that you gonna have to provide it, in my case there was no "id" on the top-level object, so I gave it the "per_page" as an id to make it work ...

```
const dataSchema = new schema.Entity("data");
const coursesSchema = new schema.Entity( "info", 
{ 
    data: [dataSchema]
}, { idAttribute: "per_page" } );

const normalizedData = normalize(data, coursesSchema);
```

By the way the "answer" provided by @Drew Reese is way simpler and cleaner in this kind of flat object response that I got.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears to already be in some reduced/normalized form as I don't see any nested, or repeated data structures. I think a simple array::reduce on your data is sufficient for your needs.

```
// Reduce data array to map [element.id => element]
const dataObject = data.reduce((dataObject, item) => {
  dataObject[item.id] = item;
  return dataObject;
}, {});
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category_id: 1,
    creator_id: 1,
    instructor_id: 1,
    difficulty_id: 1,
    status_id: 1,
    title: "hebae",
    overview: "Course Overview",
    deleted_at: null,
    created_at: "2020-01-02 15:16:08",
    updated_at: "2020-01-02 15:16:08"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category_id: 1,
    creator_id: 1,
    instructor_id: 2,
    difficulty_id: 1,
    status_id: 1,
    title: "update course 1",
    overview: "Course Overview",
    deleted_at: null,
    created_at: "2020-01-02 15:18:40",
    updated_at: "2020-01-02 15:19:06"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    category_id: 1,
    creator_id: 1,
    instructor_id: 1,
    difficulty_id: 1,
    status_id: 1,
    title: "hebaTest",
    overview: "Course Overview",
    deleted_at: null,
    created_at: "2020-01-02 15:24:09",
    updated_at: "2020-01-02 15:24:09"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    category_id: 2,
    creator_id: 1,
    instructor_id: 1,
    difficulty_id: 1,
    status_id: 1,
    title: "hebaTest",
    overview: "Adile",
    deleted_at: null,
    created_at: "2020-01-02 15:25:03",
    updated_at: "2020-01-02 15:25:03"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    category_id: 2,
    creator_id: 1,
    instructor_id: 1,
    difficulty_id: 1,
    status_id: 1,
    title: "hebaTest",
    overview: "Adile",
    deleted_at: null,
    created_at: "2020-01-02 15:33:06",
    updated_at: "2020-01-02 15:33:06"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    category_id: 1,
    creator_id: 1,
    instructor_id: 1,
    difficulty_id: 1,
    status_id: 1,
    title: "Course Title",
    overview: "Course Overview",
    deleted_at: null,
    created_at: "2020-01-05 08:24:56",
    updated_at: "2020-01-05 08:24:56"
  }
];

// Reduce data array to map [element.id => element]
const dataObject = data.reduce((dataObject, item) => {
  dataObject[item.id] = item;
  return dataObject;
}, {});

console.log(dataObject);
```

Comment: I know, you're absolutely correct, but the idea was to figure out how schema and "normalizr" work in general and why I'm getting the "undefined".
I was able to figure out where I went wrong, and that is "normalizr" needs some kind of an "id" on the top level, and if it can't find that you gonna have to provide it, and that's what I did ...

Comment: `
         const dataSchema = new schema.Entity("data");
            const coursesSchema = new schema.Entity(
                "info",
                {
                    data: [dataSchema]
                },
                {
                    idAttribute: "per_page"
                }
            );
            const normalizedData = normalize(data, coursesSchema);
`

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as it seems logical in my case, but as I said I was trying to figure out what I did wrong.
Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Ruby You are allowed to answer your own questions, and I think you should as it would technically be the *correct* answer to the original question, not just an alternative solution "that works".